# Is User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier) getting data from the database?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-identity

If I do this, to find the ID of the logged in user:

```
Guid uId = Guid.Parse(User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier));
```

Does the database get queried via UserManager, or does the information reside somewhere else? In a cookie?

Some times, I want to load related data on the `ApplicationUser`, and I don't want to take two trips to the database. I'm not sure if this counts as two trips:

```
Guid uId = Guid.Parse(User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier));
ApplicationUser user = await db.Users
    .Include(c => c.City)
    .Where(u => u.Id == uId).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

I'm pretty sure this counts as two:

```
var usr = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
ApplicationUser user = await db.Users
    .Include(c => c.City)
    .Where(u => u.Id == usr.Id).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`User.FindFirstValue` works with current HttpContext (see [`User`](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/ControllerBase.cs#L195) property) and has nothing to do with a database.
Instead, it works with current HTTP request and cookies.